# Pod stuck in terminating status but then doesn't exist

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, microk8s

I have a pod in my microk8s cluster that is stuck in terminating status, but when I try to forcefully delete it or remove its finalizers, it appears as if it doesn't exist.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME           READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
net-exporter   1/1     Terminating   0          109m
$ kubectl describe pod net-exporter
Error from server (NotFound): pods "net-exporter" not found
```

I've even tried kubectl describe net_exporter and it doesn't work.

Any idea of how could I debug this issue?

I've tried:

- Deleting the namespace the pod is in, but the resource would stay in
  the void, so the api server doesn't allow me to.
- Checking the ctr container running with microk8s `ctr container ls`, but there's no running container.
- Any way of accessing the pod with `kubectl`, but it always outputs the Not found error
- `microk8s reset`. The node resets but the pod stays there in terminating status

Comment: Is the node pod running in a ready state? Tried with --grace-period=0?

Comment: As it looks like it doesn't exist by the kubectl command, I can't apply the --grace-period=0.                                                                                                                      `$ kubectl delete pod net-exporter --force --grace-period=0
Warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
Error from server (NotFound): pods "net-exporter" not found`